# typo3 flexform html content element add in extension

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

how could i can add  html content element in flexform  in typo3.
I have tried

```
<settings.sDEF1.sociallinks>
                                        <TCEforms>
                                            <exclude>1</exclude>
                                            <label>Social Links</label>
                                            <config>
                                                <type>text</type>
                                                <renderType>t3editor</renderType>
                                                <format>html</format>
                                                <cols>30</cols>
                                                <rows>5</rows>
                                            </config>
                                        </TCEforms>
                    </settings.sDEF1.sociallinks>
```

which not working.

ref : https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Text/Index.html#rendertype

Comment: An idea... you could use a normal text-input field and display it with fluid  <f:format.html> tag

Answer (score 0):

```
        <options.richTextArea>
            <TCEforms>
                <exclude>1</exclude>
                <label>
                    Rich Text Area
                </label>
                <config>
                    <type>text</type>
                    <rows>5</rows>
                    <cols>300</cols>
                    <enableRichtext>true</enableRichtext>
                </config>
                <defaultExtras>richtext[]</defaultExtras>
            </TCEforms>
        </options.richTextArea>
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation/comments to what this is doing?